# How to get correct hierarchical uri using MediaStore EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI

Tags: android, android-intent, uri

I'm baffled by two versions of uri pointing to same image file.

The uri I'm getting from `data.getData()` on Intent data works fine with Picasso. It's identification by the debugger was  `{Uri$HierarchicalUri @5962}`,   but when I tried to use `MediaStore` to get the uri from `Media.DATA` I got a different uri that doesnt work with Picasso. The debugger identified it as `{Uri$StringUri@6079}`.

How do I extract the `HierarchicalUri` from `MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI`?

Following is my code:

```
private void openFileChooser() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
    intent.setType("image/*");
    startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
}//openFileChooser


public Uri getImageUriTest() {
    ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
    Uri mediastoreUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    Uri resultUri = null;

    Cursor imageCursor = contentResolver.
            query(mediastoreUri, null, null, null, null);

    imageCursor.moveToFirst();

    int indexImageAbsolutePath = imageCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    String absolutePath = imageCursor.getString(indexImageAbsolutePath);

    resultUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.getContentUri(absolutePath);
    return resultUri;
}//getImageTestUri()


@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK
            && data != null && data.getData() != null) {

        imageUri = data.getData();
        imageUriTest = getImageUriTest();

        Picasso.get().load(imageUri).into(imageView);
    }
}//OnActivityResult
```

Comment: "I got a different uri that doesnt work with Picasso" -- what does this mean? When you enabled Picasso's debug logging, what did the stack trace show you? Start with that, before you make assumptions that the internal representation of a `Uri` object is somehow to blame.

Comment: The uri from the Intent is : [content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/-1/1/content%3A%2F%2Fmedia%2Fexternal%2Fimages%2Fmedia%2F80/ORIGINAL/NONE/1963529294]       but the uri using MediaStore is :    [content://media//storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20181201_133319.jpg/images/media]

Comment: @CommonsWare I used Android Studio debugger. But they are different uri. The above outputs of the uri are from :  Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult: " + "[" + imageUri + "] \n\n [" + imageUriTest + "]")  I also noticed that the ending number of the HierarchicalUri changes every time I pick the image while the StringUri is constant.

Comment: Also the String uri works with ImageView but isnt applicable in Picasso.

Comment: I do not know what "isnt applicable in Picasso" means. When you enabled Picasso's debug logging, what did the stack trace show you? That will tell you what your real underlying problem is. It is not the difference between `Uri$HierarchicalUri` and `Uri$StringUri`. Instead, it is the difference in your access rights to the content. BTW, I suspect that you will have better luck if you do not use the `DATA` value with `MediaStore`, but rather construct a `MediaStore` `Uri` from the `ID` using `ContentUris.withAppendedId()`.

Comment: Thx CommonswWare I'll use your advice.